# ¿Cómo unir dos data frames por una o dos columnas en común?

Tags: r, rstudio

Buen día,

Tengo dos dataframes de un mismo sitio, pero que corresponden a años diferentes. Es decir, uno de ellos tiene de los años 2008 a 2010, y el otro de los años 2011 a 2014. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo unirlos de forma tal, que se conecten  por los años y por una columna en común que se llama "PM10". He intentado con merge, pero no obtengo el resultado que espero.

A continuación, una muestra del primer data frame:

```
tibble [1,096 x 22] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ rowid             : num [1:1096] 2487133 2487134 2487135 2487136 2487137 ...
$ date              : Date[1:1096], format: "2008-01-01" "2008-01-02" ...
$ site              : chr [1:1096] "AEROPUERTO" "AEROPUERTO" "AEROPUERTO" "AEROPUERTO" ...
$ EnvAut            : chr [1:1096] "CORPAMAG - CAR DEL MAGDALENA" "CORPAMAG - CAR DEL MAGDALENA" "CORPAMAG - CAR DEL MAGDALENA" "CORPAMAG - CAR DEL MAGDALENA" ...
$ Latitude          : num [1:1096] 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 ...
$ Longitude         : num [1:1096] -74.2 -74.2 -74.2 -74.2 -74.2 ...
$ AveragingTimeHours: num [1:1096] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
$ Year              : num [1:1096] 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 ...
$ Units             : chr [1:1096] "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" ...
$ COD_DEP           : num [1:1096] 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 ...
$ NOM_DEP           : chr [1:1096] "MAGDALENA" "MAGDALENA" "MAGDALENA" "MAGDALENA" ...
$ COD_MUN           : num [1:1096] 47001 47001 47001 47001 47001 ...
$ NOM_MUN           : chr [1:1096] "SANTA MARTA" "SANTA MARTA" "SANTA MARTA" "SANTA MARTA" ...
$ StationType       : chr [1:1096] "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" ...
$ CO                : logi [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ NO                : logi [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ NO2               : logi [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ O3                : logi [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ PM10              : num [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ PM2.5             : num [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ PST               : num [1:1096] 166 NA NA NA NA NA 251 NA NA 244 ...
$ SO2               : logi [1:1096] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
- attr(*, "spec")=
 .. cols(
 ..   rowid = col_double(),
 ..   date = col_date(format = ""),
 ..   site = col_character(),
 ..   EnvAut = col_character(),
 ..   Latitude = col_double(),
 ..   Longitude = col_double(),
 ..   AveragingTimeHours = col_double(),
 ..   Year = col_number(),
 ..   Units = col_character(),
 ..   COD_DEP = col_double(),
 ..   NOM_DEP = col_character(),
 ..   COD_MUN = col_double(),
 ..   NOM_MUN = col_character(),
 ..   StationType = col_character(),
 ..   CO = col_logical(),
 ..   NO = col_logical(),
 ..   NO2 = col_logical(),
 ..   O3 = col_logical(),
 ..   PM10 = col_number(),
 ..   PM2.5 = col_number(),
 ..   PST = col_double(),
 ..   SO2 = col_logical()
 .. )
```

Nuevamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Laura, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo del resultado que esperas?

Comment: Buen día Lumartor, en la respuesta que me dieron se ejemplica el resultado que me gustaría obtener, no obstante, los data frame tienen un número diferente de columnas, por lo cual me muestra error. Me gustaria poder unirlos por una columna en común llamada "PM10", y por la fecha. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es unir dos data frames, pero solo las dos columnas "date" y "PM10", debes seleccionar las columnas con el mismo encabezado y luego unirlos con rbind para obtener un data frame. Si unes dos data frames con rbind con distintas columnas obtienes un error:

```
>rbind(dt1, dt2)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

Para seleccionar únicamente las dos columnas utiliza:

```
dt1[c("date", "PM10")]
```

Con lo que obtendrás un data frame.

Para unir dos data frames utiliza rbind:

```
datos_unidos <- rbind(dt1[c("date", "PM10")], dt2[c("date", "PM10")])
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Lumartor! Es exactamente lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro si esto es lo que buscas.

```
datos1<-data.frame( PM10=c("1","2","3"),
date=c("2016-01-01","2017-02-01","2018-02-01"))

datos2<-data.frame( PM10=c("4","5","6"),
date=c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01","2021-02-01"))



   PM10       date
    1 2016-01-01
    2 2017-02-01
    3 2018-02-01

   PM10       date
    4 2020-01-01
    5 2020-02-01
    6 2021-02-01


datos3= rbind(datos1,datos2)


   PM10       date
    1 2016-01-01
    2 2017-02-01
    3 2018-02-01
    4 2020-01-01
    5 2020-02-01
    6 2021-02-01
```

rbind coloca un df debajo del otro si estos tienen el mismo nombre en las columnas.

Comment: ¡Buen día! Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, sí es lo que busco, pero el número de columnas no coincide entre los dos data frame, no obstante, ambos tienen una columna igual llamada PM10, que es la que me importa a la hora de unirlos, además de la fecha. ¿Sabes qué podría hacer? ¡Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: pero si la que te importa es PM10 y la fecha ¿para que quieres el resto? Intenta poner un ejemplo de los dos df que tienes y el resultado al que quieres llegar para poder entenderte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que está pidiendo es lo que en base de datos se conoce como "join", o sea la unión de filas a partir de un dato en común.

```
df1 <- data.frame( PM10 = c("1","2","3", NA),
                   date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04"))
        
df2 <- data.frame( PM10 = c("1","5","3", NA),
                   date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04"),
                   otra = runif(4))

merge(df1, df2, by = c("date", "PM10"), all = TRUE)

        date PM10      otra
1 2021-01-01    1 0.7789989
2 2021-01-02    2        NA
3 2021-01-02    5 0.4031505
4 2021-01-03    3 0.1677867
5 2021-01-04 <NA> 0.3626500
```

En este caso, la "clave" para unir las filas es  `c("date", "PM10")`, y el truco es `all = TRUE`, dónde nos aseguramos no perder ninguna fila, ya que sino el resultado final serían solo aquellas en las que coincide la clave.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Patricio!